# Animation loop finishes in 8 meters at 17 frames, how fast is it going?

Tags: unity, animation, blender

So I made this model in Blender and synced its walk cycle using an animated path that was 8 meters long at 17 frames. But I don't know how to sync it when moving the model using a rigidbody.

Comment: At what framerate?

Comment: @DMGregory it was animated at 24FPS in Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply through:

```
(8 m) / (17 frames) * (24 frames/s)

= 192/17 m/s
= 11.2941176470588 m/s
```

Or you can enable [root motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) in your animation to let the animated content drive the GameObject's motion directly.